# Gravity Forms - Adding Custom Event not firing through Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, event-listener, gravityforms

I am trying to have a tag fire on a form (using Gravity Forms), when someone clicks the submit button, and they then land on the confirmation "Thank You" page.

Here are the steps I took:

1. I created a [custom HTML tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IrVc.jpg) and added a trigger for all pages.
2. Then, I added a tag with a Custom Event Trigger with the name "formSubmission", to fire on All Custom Events.

This tag is not firing when I test out the form, and I am wondering if I messed up something with the code on the custom HTML tag.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

you may not need document ready hook in your custom tag. This works in my tags:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('formSubmission', function(event) {
  dataLayer.push( ... )
// other logic
})
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! The issue is that I need it only to work when all required fields are filled out. Is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I suppose 'gform_confirmation_loaded' is handling this

Comment: Yes, but then the tag doesn't fire.This was the article I used: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/track-gravity-forms-with-google-tag-manager/